# Booting from nfs hangs after remounting "root and kernel" file system

Tags: boot, mount, systemd, nfs

```
[  OK  ] Finished Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
         Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
[   19.905402] systemd-journald[1486]: Journal effective settings seal=no compress=yes compress_threshold_bytes=512B
[   19.919293] systemd-journald[1486]: Fixed min_use=1.9M max_use=9.8M max_size=1.2M min_size=512.0K keep_free=4.9M n_max_files=100
[   19.927851] systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: ConditionNeedsUpdate=/etc succeeded.
[   19.932942] systemd-journald[1486]: Reserving 2240 entries in hash table.
[   19.949073] systemd-journald[1486]: Vacuuming...
[   19.957832] systemd-journald[1486]: Vacuuming done, freed 0B of archived journals from /run/log/journal/e1e5e8c53feef773ecb2dd4445922f16.
[   19.960858] systemd[1]: Failed to read pids.max attribute of cgroup root, ignoring: No such file or directory
[   19.972072] systemd-journald[1486]: Flushing /dev/kmsg...
[   20.007901] systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: Passing 0 fds to service
[   20.023398] systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: About to execute: /usr/bin/systemd-sysusers
[   20.071506] systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: Forked /usr/bin/systemd-sysusers as 1643
[   20.112674] systemd[1]: systemd-sysusers.service: Changed dead -> start
[   20.125614] systemd[1]: Starting Create System Users...
         Starting Create System Users...
[   20.156246] systemd[1]: Received SIGCHLD from PID 1488 (systemd-modules).
[   20.172570] systemd[1]: Child 1488 (systemd-modules) died (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
[   20.207556] systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Failed to read oom_kill field of memory.events cgroup attribute: No such file or directory
[   20.235760] systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Child 1488 belongs to systemd-modules-load.service.
[   20.259301] systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
[   20.272363] systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Changed start -> exited
[   20.280484] systemd-journald[1486]: systemd-journald running as PID 1486 for the system.
[   20.280536] systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Job 21 systemd-modules-load.service/start finished, result=done
[   20.290483] systemd-journald[1486]: Sent READY=1 notification.
[   20.300302] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Modules.
[  OK  ] Finished Load Kernel Modules.
[   20.324133] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Got notification message from PID 1486 (READY=1, STATUS=Processing requests...)
[   20.336268] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Changed start -> running
[   20.343416] systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Job 11 systemd-journald.service/start finished, result=done
[   20.353666] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[  OK  ] Started Journal Service.
[   20.371241] systemd[1]: systemd-journald-dev-log.socket: Changed listening -> running
[  OK  ] Finished Load/Save Random Seed.
         Mounting Kernel Configuration File System...
         Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
         Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
[  *** ] (6 of 7) A start job is running for…ersistent Storage (26s / 1min 31s)
[  201.783150] nfs: server 10.10.20.2 not responding, still trying
[  226.359118] nfs: server 10.10.20.2 not responding, still trying
[  255.031099] nfs: server 10.10.20.2 not responding, timed out
[  435.255106] nfs: server 10.10.20.2 not responding, timed out
[  441.399099] nfs: server 10.10.20.2 not responding, timed out
[  615.479112] nfs: server 10.10.20.2 not responding, timed out
[  626.743092] nfs: server 10.10.20.2 not responding, timed out
[  795.703192] nfs: server 10.10.20.2 not responding, timed out
[  812.087098] nfs: server 10.10.20.2 not responding, timed out
```

U-Boot parameters:

```
dhcp;
nfs ${kernel_addr} ${serverip}:/export/boot/Image;
nfs ${fdt_addr} ${serverip}:/export/boot/armada.dtb;
set bootargs "$console root=/dev/nfs rw rootfstype=nfs nfsrootdebug ip=dhcp  nfsroot=${serverip}:/export,nolock,vers=4,tcp rootwait earlyprint=p1011,0x7ff80000 debug";
booti ${kernel_addr} - ${fdt_addr};
```

"/etc/exports":

```
/export *(rw,nohide,insecure,no_subtree_check,async,no_root_squash)
```

Answer (score 0):

After getting to this part of the boot sequence, Linux attempts to remount it's file systems.  It's currently hanging because even though it had access to the nfs file system, after remounting using fstab, it will lose access to the nfs share. For nfs to work, this necessitates that an entry for the root directory be added into fstab as well as the firewall to enable nfs to communicate through the wall.